# Way to evaluate this algebraic expression by hand without going insane?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**EDIT**: fixed asymmetrical denominator!

I was following along with a proof of [Routh's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routh%27s_theorem), and the final expression for the area of the enclosed triangle is
$$ 1 - \frac{x}{xz + x + 1} - \frac{y}{xy + y + 1} - \frac{z}{yz + z + 1} $$
(or something extremely similar).

It's supposed to simplify to 
$$\frac{(xyz - 1)^2}{(xz + x + 1)(xy + y + 1)(yz + z + 1)} $$

However, I've tried doing the simplification by hand, but to no avail.

Using the `WolframAlpha[...]` function in Mathematica and then doing a step-by-step solution gives a few pages' worth of expansions that are obviously beyond a mortal.

Is there any way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: "or something extremely similar"??? Please check your expressions (both of them) since you give them out of context and don't explain where they come from - and they don't have any obvious symmetry properties (as stated) between $x,y,z$ which would be expected for a triangle. Setting $x=y=0$ gives $1-z=1$, which is false unless $z=0$ and you give no reason why that should be so.

Comment: I'm guessing the last fraction is actually $$\frac z{yz+z+1}$$ to make for full symmetry in the expression.

Comment: @MarkBennet yes, there was a typo in the original question, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy if you fix your starting expression. The last term is $\frac{z}{yz+z+1}$ you changed that $z$ in the denominator to $y$, making it unsymmetrical.

Answer (score 1):

Setting your two expressions equal to each other and mutliplying by the denominators and simplifying I get:

$$ (y-z)(1+ x z + x^2 y z) = 0$$

Which means in general they are not equal. Or so it would seem.

Added:

Going off the idea of a typo: if you change the $(y z + y + 1)$ to $( y z + z + 1)$ then it simplifies to the stated answer (with the same change).

Comment: Yes, but how is the simplification done? I've taken a common denominator and everything, but ... the algebra gets too messy. Is there any "elegant" way?

Comment: I don't think there is a simpler way to prove it "by hand" than just getting your common denominator and simplifying. Sometimes nothing will save you from a lot of algebra--although they don't usually belabor such situations in text books.

Comment: Computer algebraic programs can help simplify for you but this is not any more elegant, it's just a short cut.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with $$1 - \frac{x}{xz + x + 1} - \frac{y}{xy + y + 1} - \frac{z}{yz + y + 1}$$ I arrived to $$\frac{x^2 y^2 z^2+x^2 y^2 z-x^2 y z^2-x y z-x z^2+y-z+1}{(x y+y+1) (x z+x+1) (y z+y+1)}$$ Probably typo's somewhere.

Comment: Yeah, the denominator of the last fraction should be $yz + z + 1$.